# Why PHP not displaying complete file content on browser if file has '=>' symbol inside?

Tags: php, html, file-handling

Hi I tried reading files (which has '**=>**' inside them) in PHP using different ways. When I'm displaying the content on browser, every time I'm getting all the text after this (=>) symbol. Why is this happening? Whats the solution?

configurables.txt file content:

```
<?php $arr = array('a' => 1); ?>
```

My Code:

```
<?php
    $configFile = 'configurables.txt';
    $fileHandler = fopen($configFile, 'r');
    echo fread($fileHandler, filesize($configFile));
?>
```

Output:

1); ?>

Comment: Please show your code and describe your problem more precisely.

Comment: I sounds like you are rendering your file contents as html. Hard to tell though as you are not providing any useful information.

Comment: Hi @BartoszZasada I updated the question with code.

Comment: Instead of reading the file, you should include it, as it is PHP-code

Comment: @jeroen I updated the question with additional info.

Comment: hi @Michel I need to do file operations like reading this file and update it.

Comment: If you need to update the contents, you should not use a php file. Instead use a format that is more suitable for storing and parsing data like a json or an ini file.

Comment: @jeroen thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your probably opening it in a browser, you'll probably find the content is there (try view source), but your browser is trying to make HTML sense of the code.  It's seeing

```
<?php $arr = array('a' => 1); ?>
```

And taking

```
<?php $arr = array('a' =>
```

As being the first tag (the > is the close of the tag).

Hence the only thing outside the tag is

```
 1); ?>
```